# Remove duplication from sql query

Tags: sql-server

Trying to select the total delivery from each store where the status is 100, some cases one repair number having 2 100(status delivery). how i can remove all the duplicated from selection even no need one means if its duplicated should cancel that repair from counting. kindly check my code below that's what i reach now.

```
SELECT        UL.StoreName, COUNT(DISTINCT JT.REPAIRNO) AS TotalDelivery
FROM            DataDetails AS UL LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          JOBTRACKING AS JT ON UL.storeID = JT.store_code
WHERE        (CAST(JT.created_Date AS date)='2017-03-08')

             AND JT.JOBSTATUS=100
GROUP BY UL.StoreName
```

for example

```
Name    TotalDelivery
ABC 4
XYZ 4
```

this one come from

```
RepairNo    Store   Status  CreatedDate
1000    ABC 100 3/8/2017
1001    ABC 100 3/8/2017
1001    ABC 100 3/8/2017
1008    ABC 100 3/8/2017
1009    ABC 100 3/8/2017
1011    XYZ 100 3/8/2017
1011    XYZ 100 3/8/2017
1013    XYZ 100 3/8/2017
1014    XYZ 100 3/8/2017
1015    XYZ 100 3/8/2017
1015    XYZ 100 3/8/2017
```

need the result as below

```
Name    TotalDelivery
ABC 3
XYZ 2
```

it will return all the rows and removes duplication but it will return one from duplicate , i want to remove that one also. only a row those dont have any duplucates. thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `distinct` ??

Comment: Please provide the current results and expected results

Comment: i am using distinct already

Comment: @NAJEEB:see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the non-duplicate results, you need to use `SUB QUERY` clause to filter them out. Try the below query.

> Updated

```
SELECT UL.StoreName, COUNT(1) AS TotalDelivery
FROM DataDetails AS UL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOBTRACKING AS JT 
ON UL.storeID = JT.store_code
WHERE CAST(JT.created_Date AS date)='2017-03-08'
AND JT.JOBSTATUS=100
AND JT.REPAIRNO IN (SELECT REPAIRNO from JOBTRACKING j WHERE j.store_code = UL.storeID GROUP BY j.REPAIRNO HAVING COUNT(1) = 1)
GROUP BY UL.StoreName, UL.storeID
```

> Test Script

```
CREATE TABLE #DataDetails
(
StoreName CHAR(3), storeID int
)

CREATE TABLE #JOBTRACKING
(
store_code int, REPAIRNO INT, JOBSTATUS INT, created_Date DATE
)

INSERT #DataDetails VALUES( 'ABC', 1), ('XYZ', 2)
INSERT #JOBTRACKING VALUES (1, 1000, 100, '2017-03-08'), (1, 1001, 100, '2017-03-08'),  (1, 1001, 100, '2017-03-08'),  (1, 1008, 100, '2017-03-08'),  (1, 1009, 100, '2017-03-08')
                     ,(2, 1011, 100, '2017-03-08'), (2, 1011, 100, '2017-03-08'),  (2, 1013, 100, '2017-03-08'),  (2, 1014, 100, '2017-03-08'),  (2, 1015, 100, '2017-03-08'),  (2, 1015, 100, '2017-03-08')


SELECT UL.StoreName, COUNT(1) AS TotalDelivery
FROM #DataDetails AS UL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #JOBTRACKING AS JT 
ON UL.storeID = JT.store_code
WHERE CAST(JT.created_Date AS date)='2017-03-08'
AND JT.JOBSTATUS=100
AND JT.REPAIRNO IN (SELECT REPAIRNO from #JOBTRACKING j WHERE j.store_code = UL.storeID GROUP BY j.REPAIRNO HAVING COUNT(1) = 1)
GROUP BY UL.StoreName, UL.storeID
```

> Results

```
+-----------+---------------+
| StoreName | TotalDelivery |
+-----------+---------------+
| ABC       |             3 |
| XYZ       |             2 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: returning total delivery is 1

Comment: its same result

Comment: @NAJEEB, please try updated query. It should solve the problem. Next time when you post the query, please consider using the [best practice](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to post your query. It's easy for us to help quickly, if you post the schema, test data, expected vs actual outputs and what you have tried already.

Comment: sure @Venu , i will try to put all the details, still its returning 1 for all the stores. i will try to create temp table and sort from there. thank you.

Comment: @NAJEEB, I have added my test tables, data and the results. I got the results what you are looking for. Am I missing some relation with the test data?

Answer (score -1):

I need more details but as I understand, Firstly you should prepare the total select data list result. For example in the inner select you can group the data and eleminate the all concurrent or redundant data or you can apply where criteria then use outer select and group by GROUP BY UL.StoreName and then you will get the true answer. Do not use distinct !

Comment: How ABC count to 3 ? 1000 ABC 100 
1001 ABC 100 
1001 ABC 100 
1008 ABC 100 
1009 ABC 100 there is 4 distinct record ? ok if you group it (2 1001) and others 1 count total is 4 how it can 3 ? am I missing something ?